# SSIS failed to run with conversion error

Tags: ssis

I encountered an error while running the SSIS. I had changed the destination column datatype to both varchar(MAX) and TEXT but the error is still showing. Any idea?

> Error at Emp Data Source [SQL Server Destination [55]]: The column ""EAM"" because the conversion between
>   types DT_STR and DT_TEXT is not supported.

Comment: Are you getting this error from data conversion task?

Comment: In which step it returns to you the error?

Comment: Yes, the error happened during data conversion task.

Comment: I think you might need to change the **input data type** from DT_STR to DT_TEXT too. Or add a _Data Flow Transformations > Data Conversion_ according to [this article](http://scottsdalewebstudio.com/blog/ssis-column-conversion-between-dt_str-and-dt_text-is-not-supported/).